# Help. I can't type 女 using Microsoft's IME

Tags: discussion

For some reason the 女 kanji is missing from the Microsoft IME. When I type 'onna' none of the suggestions are the 女 kanji. I also can't use it in words, for example, when I type 'onna no ko' the IME converts it to this: 恩あの子

What's going on?, please help :c

Comment: This is a wild guess but aren't you typing おんあ? 女 should be typed *onnna* and it should be typed おんな.

Comment: Typing "nn" to produce ん on its own is a normal aspect of typing in Japanese. Not just for おんな.

Comment: Ohhh, I started learning japanese a few days ago and I didn't know that. Thank you!

Comment: "on'na", with an apostrophe before the second "n", should also work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to type it with 3 n's as two only produce the ん sound.

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion, you can it by typing "onnna".

## Following is my thinking

Characters are parse from the beginning.

If "onna" is parsed as "おんな", we can't input "おな" by typing "ona".
In such world, "ona" is parsed as "おんあ"

So "n" need special treatment like following.

- な：na
- に：ni
- ぬ：nu
- ね：ne
- の：no
- ん：nn
- なに：nani
- なんですか：nanndesuka

If you type "onna", its parsed as "o:お", "nn:ん", "a:あ".

So you can input 女 by typing "onnna". it is parsed as "o:お", "nn:ん", "na:な".

## Summary

If you want to input "チキン南蛮", you must type "tikinnnanbann".

Comment: "tikinnnanbann", with one "n" before the "b", must work.

Comment: Thank you, I made a mistake. I've fixed.